# addIfNotExist alternative

Tags: naming, coding-standards, methods

Is there are any standards or conventions on naming methods which add something if it not exist into another something.

For example: **Store.instance().addItemIfNotExist(item)**

IfNotExist is really ugly part. What workaround may be?

Comment: Why do you think 'addItemIfNotExist' is bad? Would you rather put the 'IfNotExist' part in the documentation and force your users to read the documentation along with the code? They're always going to have to read the code, so the more information you can state in your code (and nowhere else) the better. If you still don't like this, consider instead making your class a "Set", which already has this behavior defined intrinsically.

Comment: In memory, you would use a set and just call add().  A set can only contain one copy of each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some databases use the term `Upsert` to mean "Update or Insert as needed", but you may not want the Update aspect.

In general, an `addItem()` function has an implied, expected failure if the item already exists within the database, so you could use that.  Your error handling code after the `addItem()` call would make it clear that failure because of already existing was okay.

Finally, you could consider `addItemExclusive()` to better indicate that the routine will check for existence prior to adding the item.

Answer (score 3):

an easy one that comes to mind is `addIfAbsent()`